# Changing schema name on runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I use Entity Framework 6 with an Oracle database in my project.

I have a problem: in my .edmx file (open in xml editor) all my triggers and tables has a name(schema) before the real table name or trigger etc, every time I install my project in new environment and database have a different name its try oldSchame.table and returns an error.

So for now I open .edmx in xml editor and delete all schemas name (remove schema.) and it works, but if I update my database schemas name back etc.

I have found many questions about this but all answers are old (e.g. from ~2010, and referring to Entity Framework 4); what is the best way to solve this problem for Entity Framework 6?